# Arrow color does not change in iPython when I am annotating a point on the scatterplot

Tags: annotations, visualization, jupyter-notebook

I need to annotate the point on the scatterplot. But the arrow to annotate is white or transparent. I can barely see it on a white background(but it is there). I copied solutions and it doesn't work for me again but it does work if I run the same code in the solution notebook. I added facecolor = 'black' and it didn't work either.

Plus, my background of the scatterplot is grey, but it was white. It changed at some point. And I don't know why.

Can anyone explain what could go wrong? Thank you so much.

My code is:

```
teamName = 'OAK'
years = np.arange(2000, 2004)

for yr in years: 
    df = joined[joined['yearID'] == yr]
    plt.scatter(df['salary'] / 1e6, df['W'])
    plt.title('Wins versus Salaries in year ' + str(yr))
    plt.xlabel('Total Salary (in millions)')
    plt.ylabel('Wins')
    plt.xlim(0, 180)
    plt.ylim(30, 130)
    plt.annotate(teamName, 
        xy = (df['salary'][df['teamID'] == teamName] / 1e6,  df['W'][df['teamID'] == teamName]), 
        xytext = (-20, 20), textcoords = 'offset points', ha = 'right', va = 'bottom',
        bbox = dict(boxstyle = 'round,pad=0.5', fc = 'yellow', alpha = 0.5),
        arrowprops = dict(arrowstyle = '->', facecolor = 'black' , connectionstyle = 'arc3,rad=0'))

    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's two years later (but somebody could stumble upon it using Google), but I think you need to add `edgecolor='black'` in `arrowprops`.